# Find the level of array elements in BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

We have a given array and we want to print each node's level in the BST.

For example if the given array is: {15, 6, 2, 10, 9, 7, 13}

then the answer is:

1 2 3 3 4 5 4

(it means that the level of node that stores 15 is 1 and ...)

I have some algorithms in my mind but I don't know how to implement them in code.

Comment: `I have some algorithms in my mind`, so try to explain, better as pseudo-code. Then try to implement your data types (a node at least, I guess). Come back for concrete programming question.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps that you should follow :

1. Create a binary search tree from the elements given in the array.
2. Write a function **findLevel( Node root, int value)** to find the level of any value passed to this function.
3. Iterate the array and pass each array element as an argument to **findLevel( Node root, int value)**  and print the values returned from the function.